# Retornar valor máximo de tabela no JOIN - MYSQL

Tags: mysql, join

Preciso retornar o último registro de uma tabela que está no `JOIN` da minha consulta.

Mas meu conhecimento ficou limitado e não consigo prosseguir:

Tabela Serviços:
[image: Tabela servicos]

Tabela situação:
[image: Tabela situacao]

Resultado da minha query:
[image: Resultado da minha consulta]

Minha consulta

```
SELECT s.id_servico,
       s.titulo,
       s.valor,
       st.situacao,
       st.id_situacao
FROM   servicos s
       JOIN (SELECT id_servico,
                    Max(id_situacao) AS id_situacao,
                    situacao
             FROM   situacao
             GROUP  BY 1) st
         ON st.id_servico = s.id_servico
WHERE  s.id_servico = 2872
```

Comment: Utilizando o order by para o id do serviço não resolve?

Comment: Não. Retorna a mesma coisa.. o id_situacao máximo, porém o valor (situacao) não é o correspondente

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sua query estava quase ok. Veja que, para fazer com que a query funcione precisa de dois critérios no join:

- `servicos.id_servico = situacao.id_servico`: primeiro join, que liga as tabelas
- `situacao.id_situacao = max(situacao.id_situacao)`: para que pegue o "último" registro, usando o `max`.

Esse segundo JOIN é feito na subquery, que precisa pegar o `MAX(id_suituacao)`, mas precisa ser agrupado por id_servico, ou seja, ***"traga sempre o último id_situacao para cada id_servico"***.

Isso pode ser feito assim:

```
SELECT s.id_servico, 
       s.titulo, 
       s.valor, 
       st.situacao, 
       st.id_situacao 
  FROM servicos s 
 INNER JOIN situacao st ON st.id_servico = s.id_servico
 INNER JOIN (
     select max(id_situacao) id_situacao
       from situacao
      group by id_servico) si
       ON st.id_situacao = si.id_situacao
 WHERE s.id_servico=2872;
```

Pode ver funcionando aqui: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d61e80/18

Em resumo, a subquery do segundo `JOIN` pega os maiores id_situacao por id_servico, e faz `JOIN` com a própria tabela "situacao", que tem o alias "st"

Comment: Perfeito! Obrigado.

Comment: se a resposta resolve a sua dúvida, não esqueça de marcar a resposta como aceita :)