# Utilização da função MAX em uma consulta SQL

Tags: sql, select, db2

Estou criando uma consulta onde devo trazer o percentual de ICMS na ultima entrada de um produto. Pensei em fazer da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT
    IDSUBPRODUTO,
    PERICM,             --% ICMS
    MAX(DTMOVIMENTO)
FROM
    ESTOQUE_ANALITICO EA
GROUP BY
    IDSUBPRODUTO,
    PERICM
```

Porém como alguns produtos tiveram diferentes valores de ICMS em diferentes entradas, o código acaba me retornado as vezes que o produto entrou com ICMS diferentes como o exemplo abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando na verdade eu gostaria de listar somente essa ultima entrada, do dia 18/06/2022.

Comment: Só pra esclarecer - tu queres um select que retorne sempre o ICMS mais novo (data mais recente na coluna 3) de cada produto (coluna IDSUBPRODUTO)? Se for de um produto só, acho que dá pra ordenar por data e pegar o primeiro da lista (não sei se há uma função TOP no db2, mas tenta aí)...

Comment: precisa fazer uma subquery que te retorne a data para filtra, pq o group by não vai te ajudar uma vez que há diferentes valores em icms. Eu já respondi uma duvida muito parecida aqui, veja se ajuda: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/498997/57220

Comment: outro exemplo https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/556814/selecionar-%c3%baltimo-registro-da-tabela/556852#556852

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT IDSUBPRODUTO, 
       PERICM, --% ICMS 
       DTMOVIMENTO
FROM ESTOQUE_ANALITICO EA 
/*BUSCA POR SUB SQL A MAIOR DATA POR PRODUTO 
  PRECISA DE UM "ALIAS" PARA DIFENCIAR AS INSTANCIAS
  DAS TABELAS */
WHERE DTMOVIMENTO = (SELECT MAX(EA1.DTMOVIMENTO) 
                     FROM ESTOQUE_ANALITICO EA1
                     WHERE EA1.IDSUBPRODUTO = EA.IDSUBPRODUTO)
```